# Material UI select throws event.target.getAttribute is not a function when used from within react-datatable-component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the react-datatable-component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component) and having custom cells as I want some fields to be editable.

However, I am facing a problem when using the Select field from material UI as it returns that "event.target.value" is not a function when the "onChange" event is triggered.

I created the following sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-williams-3hiyj?file=/src/App.js:50-100
where you can see the problem after selecting an option.

Any ideas will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your issue is caused by this  [line](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/master/src/DataTable/TableRow.js#L77) on react-data-table-component's `TableRow.js`, it tries to do `e.target.getAttribute('data-tag')` when row is clicked.

But when you attach an `onClick` on material-ui's `FormControl` or `Select` component and `console.log` the `event.target` you'll get

```js
{ value: 3, name: undefined }
```

The `event.target` is not an HTML element, but just an `object` with attributes `value` and `name`. Thus when react-data-table-component executes `e.target.getAttribute('data-tag')` it blows up.

---

**Possible Solution**

Attach an `onClick` handler to material-ui's `FormControl` or `Select` and stop the `event`'s propagation

```js
<FormControl onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} >
...
```

---

Also note that, doing (the code below), will not change the selected value. You have to create a component for your Select column and put the selected value to `state`. I added these fixes to the codesandbox you can find below.

```js
...
onChange={(event) => {
  row.pressTypeCode = event.target.value;
}}
```

[image: Edit exciting-hawking-7pj6o]

PS: react-data-table-component has [`ignoreRowClick`](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component#columns) for columns but I'm not sure why it's not working for our code.

Comment: Another quick fix - put the select in a box