# Materail UI TypeError: event.target.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am making a form in React using Material UI and displaying the form data in a table on client side, *the problem is* when I Select language by the select dropdown then I get an error of **TypeError: event.target.getAttribute is not a function**.
Although This language data is not displayed in the table but I need it, it needs to be stored in the database(which currently I have not implemented)

I have referred [Material UI select throws event.target.getAttribute is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581017/material-ui-select-throws-event-target-getattribute-is-not-a-function-when-used) and also this [github issue](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/issues/695) but it did not worked for me.

Currently I am not using any state management tool like redux, I am passing down props from my App component.

Please help me as in where am I going wrong

**App.js**

```
    import Projects from './components/Projects';
    import FormModal from './components/FormModal'
    import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import {nanoid} from 'nanoid'
    import DeleteModal from './components/DeleteModal';
    
    function App() {
      const [formDatas,setFormDatas] = useState(
        [
        {
        projectName: 'Test',
        projectId: nanoid(),
        nameSpace: 'John Doe'
        },
        ])
    
        // Show Table State 
        const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false)
         
      // HOOKS FORM MODAL
      const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState({
        projectName: '',
        projectDescription: '',
        nameSpace: '',
        language: ''
      })
      
      const handleAddFormChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute('name')
        console.log(fieldName)
        const fieldValue = event.target.value
    
        const newFormData = {...addFormData}
        newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue
    
        setAddFormData(newFormData)
      }
    
        // FORM SUBMIT HANDLER
        const handleAddFormSubmit = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          const newProject = {
            projectId: nanoid(),
            projectName: addFormData.projectName,
            projectDescription: addFormData.projectDescription,
            nameSpace: addFormData.nameSpace,
            language: addFormData.language
          }
          // Copy all the previous formDatas and add newProject Data
          const newProjects = [...formDatas, newProject ]
          setFormDatas(newProjects)
          //  console.log(newProject)
      
          // Clear Form Input Fields after Submitting
          setAddFormData({
            projectName: '',
            projectDescription: '',
            nameSpace: '',
            language: ''
          })
          // After Submitting close Form Modal
          handleClose()
        }
        // Delete Handler
        const deleteModalHandler = (addFormData) => {
          console.log(addFormData.projectId)
        }
    
        // MODAL OPEN CLOSE STATE
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
        const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
        const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    
      return (
        <>
        <Sidebar  showTable = {showTable} setShowTable = {setShowTable}/>
        <FormModal addFormData = {addFormData} 
                   handleAddFormChange = {handleAddFormChange} 
                   handleAddFormSubmit = {handleAddFormSubmit}
                   open = {open}
                   handleOpen = {handleOpen}
                   handleClose = {handleClose}/>
    
        <Projects  
        formDatas = {formDatas} 
        addFormData = {addFormData}  
        deleteModalHandler={deleteModalHandler} 
        showTable = {showTable} 
        setShowTable = {setShowTable}/>
        </>
    
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**FormModal.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { InputAdornment } from '@mui/material';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

export default function FormModal({handleAddFormChange, addFormData,handleAddFormSubmit,open,handleOpen,handleClose}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx = {{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end',alignItems: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <Button sx = {{ marginTop: '5%', marginRight: '4%', borderRadius: '10px '}} variant="contained" onClick={handleOpen}>Create project + </Button>
        {/* <input style = {{marginTop: '2.5%', marginRight: '5%', padding: '5px'}} type="text" placeholder = "Search..." />  */}
        <TextField sx = {{marginTop: '2%', marginRight: '4%', padding: '5px'}} placeholder = "Search..." InputProps={{
  endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="start">
      <SearchIcon />
    </InputAdornment>
   )
  }}/>
      </Box>
      
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <div style = {{height: '5vh', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <h3>Create New Project</h3>
          </div>
        <form onSubmit = {handleAddFormSubmit}>
        <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Project Name"
        name = "projectName"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth= {true}
        required = {true}
        margin ="normal"
        value={addFormData.projectName}
        onChange={handleAddFormChange}
      />
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Project Description"
        name = "projectDescription"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth = {true}
        required = {true}
        multiline
        rows = {5}
        margin ="normal"
        value={addFormData.projectDescription}
        onChange={handleAddFormChange}
      />
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Name Space"
        name = "nameSpace"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth= {true}
        required = {true}
        autoComplete = {Math.random().toString()}
        margin = "normal"
        value={addFormData.nameSpace}
        onChange={handleAddFormChange}
      />
       <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select Language</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          name = "name"
          value={addFormData.language}
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
          style = {{width: '100%'}}
        >
          <MenuItem value="english">English</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        <br />
        <div style = {{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginTop: '7%'}}>
        <Button style = {{width: '40%'}} variant = "contained" type="submit">Submit</Button>
      <Button style = {{width: '40%'}} variant = "contained" onClick = {handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </div>
      </form>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Projects.js**

```
import React from "react";
import EditModal from "./EditModal";
import DeleteModal from "./DeleteModal";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import { useState } from "react";

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    // backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    backgroundColor: "#1976D2",
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

const Projects = ({ showTable, setShowTable,addFormData, formDatas,deleteModalHandler}) => {
  //const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(true
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", marginTop: "7%" }}>
      {showTable ?  <TableContainer > {/*component={Paper}*/}
        <Table sx={{ width: '50%', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto' }} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <StyledTableCell  align="left">Project Name</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="left">Project Id</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="left">Created By</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="center">Operations</StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {formDatas.map((formData) => (
              <StyledTableRow key = {formData.projectId}>
                <StyledTableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                  {formData.projectName}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="left">
                  {formData.projectId}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="left">
                  {formData.nameSpace}
                </StyledTableCell>

                <StyledTableCell align="center">
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                    }}
                  >
                    <EditModal />
                    <DeleteModal deleteModalHandler = {deleteModalHandler}/>
                  </div>
                </StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            ))} 
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>: null}
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @Pradip Dhakal in the comment `<Select> only return the {name: '', value: ''} as a target object, this is causing the issue. There is no other objects.`

So I used Material UI [Native Select](https://mui.com/components/selects/) Component and it solved the problem
The only code that I changed in **FormModal.js**  file is below.

```
 <NativeSelect
    // defaultValue={30}
    value={addFormData.language}
    onChange={handleAddFormChange}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'language',
      id: 'uncontrolled-native',
    }}
  >
    <option value = "" disabled>Select</option>
    <option value={'english'}>English</option>
    <option value={'german'}>German</option>
  </NativeSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal code that I've try, and it's working fine in my end.

material UI version: `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",`

```js
// FormModal.js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core"

export const FormModal = ({ handleAddFormChange }) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Project Name"
            name="projectName"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth={true}
            required={true}
            margin="normal"
            value=""
            onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        />
    );
}
```

```js
// app.js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core"
import { FormModal } from "./FormModal"

const App = () => {
    const handleAddFormChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute('name')
        console.log("Name: ", fieldName)
    }
    return (
        <FormModal handleAddFormChange={handleAddFormChange} />
    );
}
```

Can you please try to breakdown your code, and start from the basic one.

Comment: My code works fine with those TextFields the only error I get is with the Select Dropdown and MenuItem

Comment: `<Select>` only return the `{name: '', value: ''}` as a target object, this is causing the issue.
There is no other objects.
But the native HTMl `<select>` does returns all the event data in target object.
So for that, you need to find out other solution, or instead use html native select element.

Comment: So I need to use the regular HTML select is that what you are referring

Comment: Thank you @Pradip Dhakal, I used  <NativeSelect> in Material UI and it worked